# Is there a better way find records with multiple sub queries

Tags: t-sql, database-performance

I am querying a database which has the following schema:

```
People
------
PersonId

PeopleTags
----------
PeopleId
TagId

Tags
----
TagId
Guid
```

A person may have multiple tags and when querying the requirement is to find people that have ALL of a set of mandatory tags and ANY of a set of optional tags.

At the moment, I'm doing a separate subquery per mandatory tag and a single subquery for the optional tags which gives me something like this:

```
SELECT People.*
FROM People
WHERE
    PeopleId IN (SELECT PeopleId FROM PeopleTags WHERE TagId IN (SELECT TagId FROM Tags WHERE Guid = '83c55f3d...')
    AND PeopleId IN (SELECT PeopleId FROM PeopleTags WHERE TagId IN (SELECT TagId FROM Tags WHERE Guid = '8159248a...')
    AND PeopleId IN (SELECT PeopleId FROM PeopleTags WHERE TagId IN (SELECT TagId FROM Tags WHERE Guid IN ('737d9015...', 'b7a5974e...')
```

There can be any number of mandatory and optional tags and we occasionally get this error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you
>   believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer
>   Support Services for more information.

Researching this error suggests that it is due to sub queries with large IN lists (which is entirely possible with the code as it stands).

Is there a better way to write this query? I have tried joining to the table multiple times but it doesn't return any results if I do.

```
SELECT People.*
FROM People
INNER JOIN PeopleTags ON PeopleTags.PersonId = People.PersonId
INNER JOIN Tags t1 on t1.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId and t1.Guid = '8159248A...'
INNER JOIN Tags t2 on t2.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId and t2.Guid = '415DF7A3...'
```

I can change

```
PeopleId IN (SELECT PeopleId FROM PeopleTags WHERE TagId IN (SELECT TagId FROM Tags WHERE Guid = '83c55f3d...')
```

to

```
PeopleId IN (SELECT PeopleId FROM PeopleTags INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId WHERE Guid = '83c55f3d...')
```

for each mandatory tag, will that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Your try to convert it to JOINs was good, but you need to LEFT JOIN, or you won't get results, like I explained in my original answer. Furthermore I added an ORDER BY, so the ones who don't have the optional tag get listed below the ones who have the optional tag. Then you can just limit the result and get the ones, the user most likely was looking for.

```
SELECT People.*
FROM People
INNER JOIN PeopleTags ON PeopleTags.PersonId = People.PersonId
INNER JOIN Tags t1 on t1.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId and t1.Guid = '8159248A...'
LEFT JOIN Tags t2 on t2.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId and t2.Guid = '415DF7A3...'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t2.TagId IS NULL THEN 99 ELSE 1 END
LIMIT 10 /*or whatever*/
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Your question is a bit unclear. Are the optional tags in the second joining to Tags (I'll asume so in my answer)? And does there have to be at least one optional tag or can there be none? If there can be none (which is how I define optionally), why care about them at all? You also don't `SELECT` them. So you can forget about the second join, which is in your case faulty by the way. You join multiple times the same column from PeopleTags to the same table on the same column. But the row in PeopleTags can not have two different values at the same time. Therefore you have no result.

When you need to make sure that there is at least one optional tag but you don't care what it is, you can optimize it like this:

```
SELECT People.*
FROM People
INNER JOIN PeopleTags ON PeopleTags.PersonId = People.PersonId
INNER JOIN Tags t1 on t1.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId 
WHERE t1.Guid = '8159248A...'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Tags t2 WHERE t2.TagId = PeopleTags.TagId)
```

Comment: Sorry it's not too clear, this is for searching so when looking for people you have a list of tags that they must have if you wish to restrict on that (e.g. Dentist, Surgeon etc) and optional tags which can be used to filter further. The result must match ALL mandatory tags if some are specified and at least one of the optional tags if any are specified.

Comment: @TrevorPilley Updated my answer. Hope I got the question right, this time.

Comment: @tomboom I ended up going with the join option just repeatedly joining on PeopleTags and Tags

Comment: no, I did it differently to that - it's probably the way I was trying to explain the problem initially but your answer didn't return the results in the way I needed. Thanks for the suggestions though.